# Suitescript Scheduled Script ERROR: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT Details: id

Tags: javascript, error-handling, suitescript

I am trying to write a simple scheduled script to copy the total YTD Sales of a Sales Rep onto the Employee record daily.  I was able to pull this information using a summary search, however, I am unable to Store the Value due to limitaions in the system.  So I cannot query against that total with future searches/workflows.  As a work around the only way I found possible to accomplish this is a daily scheduled script that will run the summary search and then copy the result for each Sales Rep into a custom field on the employee record.  However when running it fails and I get the following error:

SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT Details: id

The summary search is a transaction search grouping all transactions with a filter of Sales Rep:InternalId

Here is the code I am using.  Thank you for your help.

```
function copyValues(){
  var saleSearch = nlapiLoadSearch('transaction', 'customsearch_abi_totalsalesbyrep');
  var resultSet = saleSearch.runSearch();

  resultSet.forEachResult(function(searchResult){
    var employeeId = searchResult.getValue('salesrep.internalid');
    var employeeRec = nlapiLoadRecord('employee', employeeId);
    employeeRec.setFieldValue('custentity_abi_ytdsalesstatic', employeeRec.getFieldValue('custentityabi_totalsalebyrep')); // Copy  Total YTD Sales

    nlapiSubmitRecord(employeeRec);

    return true;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the variable employeeId is populated?

```
var employeeId = searchResult.getValue('salesrep.internalid');
```

For getting values from search results, I use this format

```
searchResult.getValue(<field id>,<join id>)
```

So in this case it would be

```
searchResult.getValue('internalid','salesrep')
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I did update the format as you suggested and I still receive the same error.

Title:  JS_EXCEPTION
Code: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT
Details: id

Comment: Are you getting a value for the variable employeeId?

Comment: No I am not getting a value for employeeID

Answer (score 0):

Sublists are mandatory even if empty.